# Extracting name and number from a string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to extract the contents in the 'Message Text', in particular the name (following the word 'Admitted') and the card number (inside the parenthesis) and then place the results into new columns.  What is the best way of achieving this?
I tried

```
access_file['Name']=access_file['Message Text'].str.extract('(.*?)')
```

but the resulting column was blank.

Thanks,

```
Message Type    Server Date/Time    Message Text    Message Date/Time
0   Card Admitted   7/25/2018 8:10  Admitted 'Santos, Samuel' (Card: 203532)   at '2nd Flr Check Rm 02-19' (IN).    7/25/2018 8:10
1   Card Admitted   7/25/2018 9:10  Admitted 'Zhu, Jin Chang' (Card: 203929)   at '2nd Flr Check Rm 02-19' (IN).    7/25/2018 9:10
2   Card Admitted   7/25/2018 9:34  Admitted 'Zhu, Jin Chang' (Card: 203929)   at '2nd Flr Check Rm 02-19' (IN).    7/25/2018 9:34
3   Card Admitted   7/25/2018 9:42  Admitted 'Klein, Erwin' (Card: 511268)   at '2nd Flr Check Rm 02-19' (IN).  7/25/2018 9:41
4   Card Admitted   7/25/2018 10:29 Admitted 'Tesis, Olga' (Card: 203047)   at '2nd Flr Check Rm 02-19' (IN).   7/25/2018 10:29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
pattern = "Admitted\s+\'(?P<name>.*)\'.*\(Card\D*(?P<card_number>\d+)\)"
df['Message Text'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Output:

```
             name card_number
0  Santos, Samuel      203532
1  Zhu, Jin Chang      203929
2  Zhu, Jin Chang      203929
3    Klein, Erwin      511268
4     Tesis, Olga      203047
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-a-string-into-columns-using-regex-in-pandas-dataframe/) could be helpful. It addresses the exactly same problem.

About the regex to be used, you can use:

`r".*Admitted\s+\'(?P<Name>[a-zA-Z, ]+)\' \(Card: (?P<digit>\d+)\).*"`

Thanks.

The example three on [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) says you can did it using a single regex. That would be more helpful and clean.

Comment: This pattern returns nan values

Comment: Edited it. I missed the space between the work Admitted and the starting of the name.